# Python time.clock() elapse a larger value when only pass a few seconds

Tags: python, timing

My code is

```
start = time.clock();
# Do something here
end = time.clock() - start;
print end;
```

There is only at most 6 seconds pass, but this program return say 18 seconds pass. I have tried time.time() and timeit module, but their result same. How this happen?

**Edit:**
I am using python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. The code I am executing is a machine learning algorithm, dataset is not small. It involves three most suspected functions, such like numpy.linalg.solve(), numpy.tanh() and scipy.linalg.orth(). Other than these, remaining code are normal code.

**Edit2:**
Yeah, the problem should be solve. Run the following code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import solve
import random
import time

start = time.clock();

M = np.random.rand( 10000, 10000 );
b = np.random.rand( 10000, 1);
ans = solve(M, b);

print time.clock() - start;
```

If your memory not enough, just reduce the size. It is around 10 seconds, but output is 107 seconds.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the clock reporting a strange time based on the code you provided. Could you provide more context for the  `# Do something here` block?

Comment: Is this on Windows or a UNIX-like system? [`time.clock` behaves completely differently on each, so it's critical to specify](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) (it's CPU time on UNIX, wall time on Windows). We also need some idea of what you're doing (are threads or subprocesses involved?). Please give a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks about your code:

- Python doesn't need semicolons, you should remove them
- You're using `time`, but you're not importing it

If I fix your code and run it, it prints `1.8363000000021223e-05`

Note the e-05 at the end, this is scientific notation for 0.000018363..

```
import time
start = time.clock()
# Do something here
end = time.clock() - start
print(end)
```

Also note that you should not be using `.clock()` in Python 3.3 or later. You should instead use time.perf_counter or time.process_time.

Comment: Given they're using `print` as a statement, I'm guessing they're still on Python 2.

Comment: I agree, but given the question, I'm not sure they're aware - and I figured others finding the answer might not be.